# Running customized mongo container in AWS EC2

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to running a cluster containing two containers, one with an image that runs a `node.js` server, and one container for a `mongo` db.

I'm following [this tutorial](https://node.university/blog/978472/aws-ecs-containers), which states to use `registry.hub.docker.com/library/mongo:latest` as the image url for the mongodb.

Now, I have a problem. Locally, when I run the mongo container on my pc, I use [the following script](https://gist.github.com/gioragutt/902320e568fc6e2293971e4a1c8e1bdc), which does two things:

1. Executes `docker run` with a `mongo` image, stating `--replSet` in the arguments
2. Runs two shell commands - initating the replica set, and setting up an initial user.

The hard part I can't wrap my head around, is the `--replSet` part.
When I run the container the the official `mongodb` image, it initiates `mongod` in some default way.

Say, I create a new `Dockerfile`, which states `FROM mongo:latest`.
To my limited understanding, the rest of the things that will happen in the custom `Dockerfile`, the `mongod` is already ran. Is there any way I can modify that way it is executes in `mongo:latest`, or modify an already active `mongod` to allow the `--replSet` option?

The shell commands on the mongo shell, as far as I understand, won't be a problem,  since this is just a couple of `RUN` commands in the `Dockerfile`.

Thanks in advance for helping!

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to run it only with the ECS task's network mode set to `bridged`.